# updating this script - change css effect on image with hover on text link

Tags: javascript, css, hover

Someone named Adam helped me with this originally. I want to make a small change to this javascript, but it's a bit past my level. Currently when you hover over one of the text links it adds a css glow effect to one of the 5 images. What I want to do is apply a different color glow effect to each of the images. For example, hover over links with environmental-health.html and the first image gets a green glow, hover over wellness-health-promotion.html links and the second image gets a purple glow, etc. Now all hovering adds the same glow.

```
window.onload = () => {
  elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-hover]');
  elements.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('mouseenter', event => {
      getTargetElement(event.target).classList.add('data-target-hover');
    });
    element.addEventListener('mouseleave', event => {
      getTargetElement(event.target).classList.remove('data-target-hover');
    });
  });
}

function getTargetElement(element) {
  const target = element.getAttribute('data-hover');
  return document.querySelector(`[data-target="${target}"]`);
}
```

```
.division-icon {
  background-color: #ff8066;
  border: solid 4px #c34a36;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.1s linear;
  position: relative;
}

.division-icon img {
  width: 50px;
}

.data-target-hover {
  transition: 0.1s linear;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px blue;
}
```

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" data-target="image1">
      <a href="environmental-health.html" title=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" data-target="image2">
      <a href="wellness-health-promotion.html" title=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/238/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="maternal-child-health.html" title=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/239/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" data-target="image4">
      <a href="adult-services.html" title=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/231/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="dental-health.html" title=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/232/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="administration.html" title=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/233/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
  </div>
</div>

<a href="1.html">1</a>
<a href="2.html">2</a>
<a href="3.html">3</a>
<a href="4.html" data-hover="image4">4</a>
<a href="5.html" data-hover="image2">5</a>
```

Comment: You could do this directly via your CSS. Use `.data-target-hover[data-target="image2"]]` as selector, and inside the rule, specify the box-shadow with the color you want for image2. And same for the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of CSS variable and data attribute for this purpose, here's a sample code based on your example (Try hovering on `4` to see it glows in red):

```js
window.onload = () => {
  elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-hover]');
  elements.forEach((element) => {
    element.addEventListener('mouseenter', (event) => {
      const targetElement = getTargetElement(event.target);
      targetElement.style.setProperty('--glow-color', element.getAttribute('data-color') || 'blue');
      targetElement.classList.add('data-target-hover');
    });
    element.addEventListener('mouseleave', (event) => {
      const targetElement = getTargetElement(event.target);
      targetElement.style.setProperty('--glow-color', element.getAttribute('data-color') || 'blue');
      targetElement.classList.remove('data-target-hover');
    });
  });
};

function getTargetElement(element) {
  const target = element.getAttribute('data-hover');
  return document.querySelector(`[data-target="${target}"]`);
}
```

```css
.division-icon {
  background-color: #ff8066;
  border: solid 4px #c34a36;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.1s linear;
  position: relative;
}

.division-icon img {
  width: 50px;
}

.data-target-hover {
  transition: 0.1s linear;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px var(--glow-color, blue);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" data-target="image1">
      <a href="environmental-health.html" title=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" data-target="image2">
      <a href="wellness-health-promotion.html" title=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/238/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="maternal-child-health.html" title=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/239/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" data-target="image4">
      <a href="adult-services.html" title=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/231/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="dental-health.html" title=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/232/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="administration.html" title=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/233/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
  </div>
</div>

<a href="1.html">1</a>
<a href="2.html">2</a>
<a href="3.html">3</a>
<a href="4.html" data-hover="image4" data-color="red">4</a>
<a href="5.html" data-hover="image2">5</a>
```